# How do i change the value of a specific item in a list with many items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Im kind of new to python and need some help.

How do i change the value of a specific item, (in this instance :"unit price for one product" in a list/dictionary with many items/products ?

```
products = [
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 1,
        "product_category": "Toy",
        "product_description": "Basketball Hoop Adjusts to Six Heights",
        "product_id": 152,
        "product_name": "Little Tikes EasyScore Basketball Set",
        "reorder_level": 36,
        "unit_price": 36.99
    },
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 4,
        "product_category": "Hardcover",
        "product_description": "Weight - 1.476 Depth - 0.00 Width - 0.00 Height - 0.00",
        "product_id": 153,
        "product_name": "The Very Quiet Cricket",
        "reorder_level": 10,
        "unit_price": 23.99
    },
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 2,
        "product_category": "Automotive",
        "product_description": "Compact 64 piece road assistance kit",
        "product_id": 154,
        "product_name": "AAA 64 Piece Premium Traveler Road Kit",
        "reorder_level": 12,
        **"unit_price": 39.99**
    },

    
     {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 3,
        "product_category": "Wireless Phone",
        "product_description": "Display: 5.1-inches Camera",
        "product_id": 155,
        "product_name": "Samsung Galaxy S5, Black 16GB (Sprint)",
        "reorder_level": 18,
        "unit_price": 699.99
    }


    
]
```

How do i change the value of one specific i.e unit price for the first product ?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know exactly which element do you want to modify?

Comment: ```products[0]['unit_price']=x...```?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to modify the unit price of the i-th item : ```products[i][unit_price"] = 31.45```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why, you can simply use list-indexing, and then set the `unit_price` of the dictionary using:

```
products[0]['unit_price']= what_ever_price
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change a item in a list with its index:

`list[index] = value`

Remember the indexing in python starts from 0, so the first element has the index of 0, second has 1, third has 2, and so on...

You can change values in a dictionary with its key:

`dictionary[key] = value`

For your example:

`products[0]['unit_price'] = new_price`

Here `products[0]` returns the first product dictionary and then you can change the 'unit_price' value.

Answer (score 0):

for accessing an element in a `list` or a `dictionary` you use the `[]` operator.
for a `list` you can access with index and for a `dict` you can access with a unique key such as `string`
so you can access the first product's `unit_price` value like this:

```
first_elem_unit_price = products[0]['unit_price']
```

and modify it like this:

```
products[0]['unit_price'] = new_price
```

Answer (score 0):

As is has been pointed out in some answers, if you know the position of the element you want to modify, you only need to do:

```
products[0]["unit_price"] = new_price  # or any other index 1, 2, 3
```

If you want to modify the product according to another condition, you use a for loop:

```
for product in products:
     if product["id"] == some_id:
         product["unit_price"] = some_price
```